# Error: Error parsing xml: Unbound Prefix when using StaggeredGridView

Tags: android, xml, android-gridview

I am trying to implement the etsy Straggred GridView but unfortunatly I can get my layout working. Here is the xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/bgg"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <com.etsy.android.grid.StaggeredGridView 
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/gvgrigview"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipChildren="true"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        app:item_margin="2dp"
        app:column_count="@integer/grid_column_count">
        </com.etsy.android.grid.StaggeredGridView>



 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

In root layout of your xml you have to add this: xmlns:staggered="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Answer (score 0):

Remove `mlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`.Just have

```
 <com.etsy.android.grid.StaggeredGridView 
    android:id="@+id/gvgrigview"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    app:item_margin="2dp"
    app:column_count="@integer/grid_column_count">
    </com.etsy.android.grid.StaggeredGridView>
```

Edit :

Looking at the one you referred you are missing the below in the root element in xml

```
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: @KevinKaburu https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView you are missing few things. Check the Usage part

Comment: is there difference between using the https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid  and  github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView  ?

Comment: I think the one you are referring is different from the one i am suggesting. Yes there is a difference

Comment: @KevinKaburu yes you are still missing something pls check the edit

Comment: Now this what I have on the parent                                      `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/bgg"
     android:orientation="vertical">`

Comment: @KevinKaburu join the chat @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49588/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-kevin-kaburu